# iOS 8 vs iOS 9 Appdelegate / ViewController method call flow

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a bit of an odd one here. Has something changed with the app lifecycle between iOS 8 and iOS 9?

In my appDelegate I have a call to post an NSNotification in the applicationDidBecomeActive method. In two view controllers I add observers for this notification. On iOS 8 devices, this works perfectly, observers are added before the post, but on iOS 9 devices, the post comes before the observers are added.

The flow I've observed is as follows (VC 1 & 2 are container views):

iOS 8 -

1. appDelegate - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
2. VC1 - viewDidLoad
3. VC2 - viewDidLoad
4. appDelegate - applicationDidBecomeActive

iOS 9 -

1. appDelegate - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
2. appDelegate - applicationDidBecomeActive
3. VC1 - viewDidLoad
4. VC2 - viewDidLoad

Is this expected behavior? [This link](https://www.progressconcepts.com/blog/ios-appdelegate-viewcontroller-method-order/) shows the order as iOS 8 behaves, which is what I want, but I don't know.

Comment: Change in the App Lifecycle would be a pretty big deal, and Apple would have definitely let the developer know. Your question above assumes View Loading = Application is Active. That many note be true. 

This could be just related to timing. To solve your problem, wouldnt it be better if you added the code that responds to the notification in viewWillAppear.

Comment: @TheAppMentor - No, moving the code to add the NSNotification observer into viewWillAppear would not work. viewWillAppear gets called after viewDidLoad. The NSNotification post is called before either of those two events. Again, on iOS 8, this is as expected - views are loaded before applicationDidBecomeActive. On iOS 9 however, I'm getting applicationDidBecomeActive before any of the views have loaded.

Comment: @TheAppMentor - also, I totally agree, Apple changing the lifecycle seems crazy, but this is what I'm seeing.